# Replace NA with random numbers within `group_by` in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have a data frame in long format and I want to replace missing values by random numbers, but I want to do this group wise with different settings...

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

imp_df <- 
  data.frame(exp=rep(letters[1:3], each=2),
             rep=1:2,
             mean=1:6,
             sd=seq(0,0.5,0.1))

df <- 
  data.frame(
    exp=rep(letters[1:3], each=20),
    rep=1:2,
    int=rnorm(60,10,5)
  )

df[sample(1:60,25,replace=F), 'int'] <- NA
```

So my data looks like above, in the `imp_df` I have the settings for the `rnorm` function based on the experiment `exp` and the replicate `rep`.

My data frame has then some missing values and I want to replace the `NA` by the random numbers.

How can I do it using `dplyr` or `tidyr`?

### Edit

After the answer from @starja, I found a quick, but maybe slow solution by using `rowwise` together with `left_join`.

```
df %>%
  left_join(imp_df) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(imp.int=if_else(
    is.na(int),
    rnorm(1, mean, sd),
    int
  )) %>%
  print(n=60)
```

Are there other ways to do this?

### Edit 2

Since the `rowwise` approach is pretty slow and I couldn't get it running within some dplyr code, I used a for loop to go through `imp_df` with the imputation settings.

This is a pretty quick solution, but not as readable as I was hoping:

```
df$imp.int <- df$int


for(line in 1:nrow(imp_df)) {
  imp_settings <- as.list(imp_df[line,])
  rows_missing_values <- which(
    df$exp == imp_settings$exp &
      df$rep == imp_settings$rep &
      is.na(df$imp.int) 
  )
  df$imp.int[rows_missing_values] <- 
    stats::rnorm(length(rows_missing_values), imp_settings$mean, imp_settings$sd)
}
```

So we first add a column `imp.int` for the imputed values and run now line by line the different imputation settings by replacing the NAs for each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could also be done:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  left_join(imp_df, by = c("exp", "rep")) %>%
  mutate(int = ifelse(is.na(int), 
                      map2(mean, sd, ~ rnorm(1, .x, .y)), int))

   exp rep       int mean  sd
1    a   1         1    1 0.0
2    a   2  10.91822    2 0.1
3    a   1  5.821857    1 0.0
4    a   2   17.9764    2 0.1
5    a   1  11.64754    1 0.0
6    a   2  5.897658    2 0.1
7    a   1  12.43715    1 0.0
8    a   2  13.69162    2 0.1
9    a   1  12.87891    1 0.0
10   a   2  1.986482    2 0.1
```

Comment: I can't find the correct words for this elegant solution! Thanks, this works like a charm!

Comment: That's my pleasure, glad I could provide assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are cleverer solutions out there that use vectorisation, but if you don't have super large data, I like to use a `purrr::map` function for this together with a small custom made function:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

imp_df <- 
  data.frame(exp=rep(letters[1:3], each=2),
             rep=1:2,
             mean=1:6,
             sd=seq(0,0.5,0.1))

df <- 
  data.frame(
    exp=rep(letters[1:3], each=20),
    rep=1:2,
    int=rnorm(60,10,5)
  )

df[sample(1:60,25,replace=F), 'int'] <- NA

replace_fun <- function(x, mean, sd) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    rnorm(1, mean, sd)
  } else {
    x
  }
}

df %>% 
  left_join(imp_df, by = c("exp", "rep")) %>% 
  mutate(int = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(int, mean, sd), replace_fun)) %>% 
  head()
#>   exp rep       int mean  sd
#> 1   a   1  1.000000    1 0.0
#> 2   a   2 10.918217    2 0.1
#> 3   a   1  5.821857    1 0.0
#> 4   a   2 17.976404    2 0.1
#> 5   a   1 11.647539    1 0.0
#> 6   a   2  5.897658    2 0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

(If you want, you can remove the mean/sd columns with `select(-c(mean, sd))`.)

Comment: reading your code and using the `left_join` I can also impute by using `rowwise()`. Might be a bit slow, because I calculate one missing value and not all per group, but it is much easier to read and doesn't need an extra function.

Comment: yes, I think `rowwise` is also a good option. Let's see if someone comes up with a truly vectorised approach

Comment: For my dataset it is much too slow... I made myself an extra step with a for loop... Which is very quick, but not as good to read... Added it to my question